# AutoCompleteTextView remove/change color divider

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to remove/change color of the delimiter in AutoCompleteTextView's popup ? In ListView I get use of the  "delimiter" parameter, but I haven't found any similar in AutoCompleteTextView.

Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777912/customize-divider-separator-in-dropdown-of-an-autocompletetextview. It should solve the problem of divider styling.

Comment: I've solved it. there's an Android array called styleable or something like that R.styleable.delimiter_autocomplete bla bla bla

Comment: @midnight can you explain your solution in more detail?

Comment: @littlefluffykitty sorry, I dont have code at hand atm - I remember I was looking through the source code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java where I found http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#autoCompleteTextViewStyle where you can actually override one of the properties, which corresponds to the delimiter color.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Adapter for your AutoCompleteTextView.
Then, you can do something like this :

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
```

The layout can be configured by you.

Comment: I've tried it and it didn't work. Could bring a working example or a link, please ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix solution, for removing the divider, might be writing a custom XML to override the style for each cell (Through the SetDropDownViewResource). After that you can change the android:popupBackground property on the autocompletetextview to match it to the color of your item's background.