# how to show divider line in autocompleteTextview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, autocompletetextview

I am trying to show divider line in autoCompleteTextView. I have tried to show divider line many ways as well as i have also google but no any answer help me.please any one help me. i have also follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12475839/4555700) but not achieve my result.

i am using style this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListViewStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="DropDownListViewStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
<item name="android:divider">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:dividerHeight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share you code